# What is the use of an OUTPUT parameter in SQL?

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures

In an **SQL** Stored Procedure/Function, we can return multiple values. Then what is the use of an **OUTPUT** parameter? I wonder why they have introduced it? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Same use in stored procedures as in regular programming languages.

Comment: Output parameters are very useful when you need to return scalar values (as opposed to tabular data) from stored procedures.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and support for stored procedures is highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to RDBMS like SQL Server then output parameters are used to capture the result set of execution in a scalar variable.

Example:

```
Create procedure dbo.sp_square @inputparam int
as
declare @outputparam int
select @outputparam = @inputparam * @inputparam 
Return @outputparam
```

Execution to get and store the output value of a sp

```
Declare @result int
exec @result = dbo.sp_square 5

select @result
```

Result

```
25
```

If you are not returning the output in the stored procedure you will still get the result after the execution but you cannot store it in a variable or use it later in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`OUTPUT` clause returns the values of each row that was affected by an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

Comment: OP is asking for `OUTPUT parameter` not `output clause`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).